# Trying to add a role to a mentioned user

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot for a game of tag. I am making it so you can mention a user and it adds the 'IT' role to them, but when they don't mention a member, it's added to them.
 My code is here:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}tag`)) {
        if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
        let roleenter = message.guild.roles.get("555947490315075600");
        let member = message.member;
        member.addRole(roleenter).catch(console.error);
        message.reply("you are now it!")
        client.channels.get("555943069271457792").send(member + " is now in!")
        await message.guild.fetchMembers();
        const role = message.guild.roles.get("555947490315075600");
        for (const member of role.members.array()) {
            await member.removeRole(role);
        }} else {
           let member = message.mentions.users.first(); 
           let roleenter = message.guild.roles.get("555947490315075600");
           member.addRole(roleenter).catch(console.error);
           message.reply("you are now it!")
           client.channels.get("555943069271457792").send(member + " is now in!")
           await message.guild.fetchMembers();
           const role = message.guild.roles.get("555947490315075600");
           for (const member of role.members.array()) {
               await member.removeRole(role);
```

Whenever I try #tag @user, it says `member.addRole is not a function` when I use it earlier on and it works.

Comment: Could you please edit the code and structure blocks properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
let member = message.mentions.users.first();
```

To this line:

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

You used the user Object of the mentioned user, but you have to use the guildMember Object because you can‘t assign a role to an user.

Comment: Those 2 lines are aexactly the same :)